# Communication between multiple activity and a fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to communicate between multiple activity and a single fragment, by callbacks.That is more than 2 activity class is going to use the same fragment.But i should not hold each activity’s instance .Let me know if any solution is there for my problem.

Comment: Use localBroadcasts

Comment: You could use the `onActivityResult()`: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: or https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating if you want to communicate fragment-activity

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "communicate"? What kind of data? If you are talking about primitive types, you can use `SharedPreferences` to easily store and access data on each activity/fragment level. Or, if you are talking about objects, you could use `Parcelable` or `Serialization`. You have many options but it really depends on what you are sending.